# Add an option to grub command line in /etc/default/grub

Tags: python, regex, ansible

On ubuntu, I'am trying to add option **disable.ipv6=1** to grub command line in /etc/default/grub file with ansible (module 'replace').
So, I need a regex (python) to find out if **disable.ipv6=1** is present and add it only if it is absent (to keep ansible idempotence).

The line :
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"`

or (after ansible first execution) : 
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet ipv6.disable=1"`

So I've tried regex : `^GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=\"([^\"]*)(?:disable\.ipv6=\d)?([^\"]*)\"$`

=> This does not work : do not take in account my non capturing group...

Thanks a lot for your help,

Pierre

Comment: Do you need a capturing group? Note that the example text is `ipv6.disable=1` and the pattern looks for `disable\.ipv6=\d` It matches the data because of `([^\"]*)` and the non capturing group that follows is optional.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about Ansible, but I would suggest to create a file in `/etc/default/grub.d` folder instead of edit your `/etc/default/grub`.

Create a new file in `/etc/default/grub.d/ipv6-disable.cfg` and paste:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT} ipv6.disable=1"
```

Much more maintainable, simple and clean

Comment: Yes obiously it is the best way :D
Thans for your help !
Pierre

Comment: You can keep idempotence just creating or deleting a custom file ```/etc/default/grub.d/ipv6-disable.cfg``` as I answer you. This way is easier than replacing content over main file ```/etc/default/grub```.

Comment: @BeardOverflow good answer, thanks. As far as I know, /etc/default is used by Debian-like distros, and so in many cases the path will simply be /etc/grub.d